# Linq groupby with where clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, razor

I am attempting to group my items and have a where clause included and I am not quite sure where to put my items.

here is what i have so far:

```
@{
var trust = new trusteeEntities();
var gen = (from g in trust.Documents               
           where g.doc_type == "Minutes"
           orderby g.meeting_date descending
           group g by g.meeting_date into f
           select g);

    foreach (var f in gen)
    {        
       <div class="documents">   
          <span class="date">@string.Format("{0:MMMM d, yyyy}", f.meeting_date)</span> 
            <p><a href="/@f.filename">@f.title</a></p>                
       </div>        
    }   
  }
```

Comment: instead of `select g` use `select f`

Comment: @lazyberezovsky where?

Comment: try to use text search :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to order the items after the grouping as `GroupBy` does not keep order. Moreover, you select the wrong items. To select the groups use select `f` instead of select `g`.

```
from g in trust.Documents
where g.doc_type == "Minutes"   
group g by g.meeting_date into f  // Groups the items g into groups called g
orderby f.Key descending          // Orders the groups by their key (which corresponds to g.meeting_date)
select f                          // Selects the group
```

I also would highly recommend you to rename your variables:

```
from document in trust.Documents
where document.doc_type == "Minutes"   
group document by document.meeting_date into documentGroup  // Groups the items g into groups called g
orderby documentGroup.Key descending                        // Orders the groups by their key (which corresponds to document.meeting_date)
select documentGroup                                        // Selects the group
```

To show the groups (not sure of that part because I've never written ASP.NET code nor HTML code):

```
foreach (var documentGroup in gen)
{        
   <div class="documents">   
      <span class="date">@string.Format("{0:MMMM d, yyyy}", documentGroup.Key)</span> 
      foreach (var document in documentGroup)
      {        
        <p><a href="/@document.filename">@f.title</a></p>                
      } 
   </div>        
}
```

### Update

Given the code in the foreach, I think you don't need to group the documents by their date. If so, the Linq query is:

```
from document in trust.Documents
where document.doc_type == "Minutes"   
orderby document.meeting_date descending
select document
```

Comment: I get does not contain a definition for "meeting_date" and no extension method down in my for statement

Comment: OK, I understand why. In that case, why do you need to group your documents? Don't your just want to sort them by date?

Comment: I needed to group them so that the documents specific to a date are listed under that date

Comment: But your are not using the groups in the `foreach`.

Comment: How would i use it in the foreach?

Comment: You need two foreach. The first that iterates through the groups, and the second that iterates through the elements of each group.

Comment: @Paradigm I've edited my post to explain how to show all groups and all documents.

Comment: Would the second one be after the label then?

Comment: Would the foreach look like this then: foreach (var f in gen)
    {        
        <div class="documents">   
            <span class="date">@string.Format("{0:MMMM d, yyyy}", f.meeting_date)</span>   
              foreach (var f in gen)
                  {      
                    <p><a href="/@f.filename">@f.title</a></p>             
        }
}
    </div>    
    
  }

Comment: It's almost that. However, in the second `foreach`, you have to iterate not through the groups but through the elements of the group `f`.
Take a look at what I've written. I've edited my post.